Get token after successful Google IAP login
Context
A frontend running on Google Cloud Run, and a backend running on Google Cloud Run too, they are both protected by IAP, and secured to require authentication. They are also both behind a Load balancer with a mapping to the api with the route /api/*. The frontend is served by a simple Nginx container.
Problem
The user logs in successfully with IAP to the frontend, but the JWT token is lost in the process. And the API calls get redirected to the login screen, but since they are XHR calls, they are stuck in the network tab. So an Authorization header is needed with the JWT token.
Question
What's the easiest / simplest way to make API calls with the authorized user token?

Are you sending the cookies in your XHR calls? No JWT are required here: IAP authenticates the user by cookie and creates a token for the user and then forwards it to Cloud Run. Of course the user ID must be authorized on the frontend and backend Cloud Run services

yes the cookies are sent, the only problem I see is maybe a CORS issue because the HTTP Options is not enabled in IAP

Here's the error from the console: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?.... (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’).

IAP should allow all origin. Configure it here: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/customizing#customizing_settings

I was setting withCredentials: truein my frontend, removing it got me to another error: (Reason: CORS preflight response did not succeed). Status code: 405. Now it's clear the OPTIONS requests should be enabled

Did Guillaume comments help you to resolve your issue, if not check this stack link which will help you to resolve your issue.

yes he helps me a lot, it's so much appreciated. Considering your link, yes my app is configured to handle CORS OPTIONS requests correctly. After enabling OPTIONS requests in IAP, now I get Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

Since your issue is resolved can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it?

It's still not resolved, but for sure I will post the solution when everything works

seems like IAP is not sending Allow Origin headers..

or even better  https://accounts.google.com/ is not allowing CORS which is normal because it shouldn't be called in XHR requests, or am I wrong ?

hum.. I guess there should be a Session affinity between the API and the front end to make this work because the Cookie is not recognized. Hence, it redirects me to authenticating again (with XHR requests), because they are in 2 different negs ?

It's also probably because I am using 2 backend services in the load balancer, and that means 2 different IAPs

The solution was to make a single Cloud run service that serves the API and the static files, because IAP generates one service for each cloud run instance, so the architecture was too complex, and having a Cloud run dedicated for the front end service over engineered.
Another approach is to have a Cloud Storage and configure a public Cloud CDN, but that adds the overhead of signing Cookies to fetch static files which doesn't bring much value as the cookie can be stolen. And the authentication is not forced on Cloud storage because IAP doesn't support Cloud storage for now.
